# What does the following statement mean?

Tags: meaning

Can anyone help me to make sense of the following statement :

> **May all sentient beings never separate from peace and happiness.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ErikKowal I was trying but this one was in my head for quiet a while and cannot figure out.

Comment: I'd not describe it as 'fatuous drivel', within a Buddhist context sentences like this one are taken very seriously.

Comment: Well, let's try to deconstruct its most problematic elements: "all sentient beings" = the universe of all creatures capable of experiencing sensation (which doesn't necessarily involve the possession of consciousness); "never separate from" = (I guess) never fail to experience. Reassembling all the elements, we end up with something like "It is desirable that the universe of all creatures capable of experiencing sensation should never fail to experience peace and happiness". (I suppose we have to infer they have consciousness if they are capable of experiencing peace and happiness.) Trite, eh?

Comment: There are no idioms involved. The statement means exactly what it means. Every word can be looked up in a dictionary of your choice, and the whole is then exactly the sum of its parts.

Answer (score 2):

It means may all conscious/sensible people (in short , good people ) maintain peace and happiness.
This way the world would remain a better place to live in.